# Css divs and h1 h2

Tags: css

I'm trying to get 3 content boxes all inline with a `h1` and `h2` tags inside them.

I have sorted the boxes, but seem to be having an issue styling the `h1` and `h2` tags. They just will not style . Not sure if i have the shorthand css correct on the `h1` and `h2`

This my css:

```
#day1, #day2, #day3 {width: 230px; height: 100px; margin-bottom:15px; background:#fff; word-wrap: break-word; display:inline-block; position:relative;}
#day1 {float: left;}
#day2 {margin-left: 15px; float: left;}
#day3 {float: right;}
#day1, #day2, #day3 h1 { font-size:18px; font-weight:200; color:#4778DE; padding:0 5px;}
#day1, #day2, #day3 h2 { font-size:12px; font-weight:200; color:#4778DE; padding:0 5px;}

#daybutton {position: absolute; display:inline-block; bottom:0; margin-left: 130px; margin-bottom:5px;}
#daybutton p { font-size:12px; color:#4d4d4d;}
#daybutton p a { font-size:14px; color:#4778DE; text-decoration:none;}
#daybutton p a:hover {color:#88B828; text-decoration:none;}
```

and the html:

```
<div id="day1">
<h1>Name Here</h1>
<h2>Job Title Here</h2>
<div id="daybutton">
<p><a href="#">Read more &gt;</a> </p>
</div>
</div>
<div id="day2">
<h1>Name Here</h1>
<h2>Job Title Here</h2>
<div id="daybutton">
<p><a href="#">Read more &gt;</a> </p>
</div>
</div>
<div id="day3">
<h1>Name Here</h1>
<h2>Job Title Here</h2>
<div id="daybutton">
<p><a href="#">Read more &gt;</a> </p>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Your selectors need a little tweaking. Try this to replace lines 5 + 6:

```
#day1 h1, #day2 h1, #day3 h1 { font-size:18px; font-weight:200; color:#4778DE; padding:0 5px;}
#day1 h2, #day2 h2, #day3 h2 { font-size:12px; font-weight:200; color:#4778DE; padding:0 5px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or if there are more div's you are planning to add then just simply wrap your all div's within container div and apply the below css for h1 and h2

```
#container h1{ font-size:18px; font-weight:200; color:#4778DE; padding:0 5px; }
#container h2 { font-size:12px; font-weight:200; color:#4778DE; padding:0 5px;}

<div id="container">
    <div id="day1">
    <h1>Name Here</h1>
    <h2>Job Title Here</h2>
    <div id="daybutton">
    <p><a href="#">Read more &gt;</a> </p>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div id="day2">
    <h1>Name Here</h1>
    <h2>Job Title Here</h2>
    <div id="daybutton">
    <p><a href="#">Read more &gt;</a> </p>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div id="day3">
    <h1>Name Here</h1>
    <h2>Job Title Here</h2>
    <div id="daybutton">
    <p><a href="#">Read more &gt;</a> </p>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```